# File upload store() not returning path Laravel

Tags: laravel

According to the docs, calling store() on a file upload should return the path of the file: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Here is my very basic example:

```
$photoPath = $this->photo->store('photos');
dd($photoPath);
```

In this case, $photoPath is returning true.

What am I doing wrong here? Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: is the $this->photo is a Request instance?

Comment: is `$this->photo` coming from request or it's a model property ?

Comment: $this->photo is an instance of TemporaryUploadedFile which extends UploadedFile:

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to upload file :

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $photoPath = $request->file('photo')->store('photos');
    dd($photoPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to upload file :

```
        public function update(Request $request)
        {
            $path = $request->file('photo')->store('photos');

            return $path;
        }
```